# Yarn fails running on Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I install `yarn` and then I would like to execute it using the next Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
....
USER node
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c","yarn install"]
```

But it fails with:

```
/bin/bash: yarn: command not found
ERROR: Service 'falink-frontend4' failed to build: The command '/bin/bash -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I just try using the next:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
....    
USER node
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn install
```

But it fails to with:

```
/bin/sh: 1: yarn: not found
ERROR: Service 'falink-frontend4' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Then I connect to the container using `docker exec -it XXXXX /bin/bash`, I run `yarn install` and it works fine. When I access inside the docker container I use `node` user as on the Dockerfile.

This is my entery Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app


#use mirrors for faster apt downloads no matter where the machine that builds the image is
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

#install required software before using nvm/node/npm/bower
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfontconfig curl git python build-essential

#add user node and use it to install node/npm and run the app
RUN useradd --home /home/node -m -U -s /bin/bash node

#allow some limited sudo commands for user `node`
RUN echo 'Defaults !requiretty' >> /etc/sudoers; \
    echo 'node ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata, /usr/bin/tee /etc/timezone, /bin/chown -R node\:node /myapp' >> /etc/sudoers;

#run all of the following commands as user node from now on
USER node

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash

#change it to your required node version
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.11.0

#needed by nvm install
ENV NVM_DIR /home/node/.nvm

#install the specified node version and set it as the default one, install the global npm packages
RUN . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && npm install -g yarn && npm install -g phantomjs@1.9.20 koa@2.0.0 koa-static@2.0.0 koa-convert@1.2.0  koa-route koa-connect-history-api-fallback koa-body-parser fs@0.0.2 axios lodash moment

ADD ./Falink_front/run_all.sh /run_all.sh

COPY ./Falink_front/webapp /myapp

ADD ./Falink_front/scrapping.js /code/scrapping.js
ADD ./Falink_front/package.json /code/package.json
COPY ./Falink_front/public /code/public
COPY ./Falink_front/src /code/src
ADD ./Falink_front/yarn.lock /code/yarn.lock

USER root
RUN chown -R node:node /code

USER node
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c","yarn install"]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still need to tweak a `ubuntu:trusty` image, this `Dockerfile`, inspired by offical [docker hub `node:latest`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/31cfb8b96b69351b3552592dd1e2d62e73a5c5b9/8.1/Dockerfile) has a functional `yarn` working.

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

#use mirrors for faster apt downloads no matter where the machine that builds the image is
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

#install required software before using nvm/node/npm/bower
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfontconfig curl git python build-essential

#allow some limited sudo commands for user `node`
RUN echo 'Defaults !requiretty' >> /etc/sudoers; \
    echo 'node ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata, /usr/bin/tee /etc/timezone, /bin/chown -R node\:node /myapp' >> /etc/sudoers;

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 node \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-team
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done

#change it to your required node version
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.11.0

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

ENV YARN_VERSION 0.24.6

RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt/yarn \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/yarn --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz

# COPY YOUR APPLICATION'S FILES HERE and CHOWN

USER node
RUN yarn --help
```

I'll see at end of build that `yarn --verion` outputs:

```
Step 14/14 : RUN yarn --version
---> Running in 9e7d8b42cd87
0.24.6
```

Comment: Really thanks!!! Finally I use a "node" docker image, but it solved my question!:)